# Detecting load of <link> resources?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization

Browsers provide load events for `<script>` and `<img>` tags.  Is there a way to detect whether a request to a  element has completed?

Specifically, I'm wishing to detect when a `<link>`'d stylesheet has been loaded.

Unfortunately, I think using a sentinel style and detecting load from a `computedStyle` isn't workable in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a simpler way to do it, but this worked for me.

Make sure your `<link>` tag has a `title` attribute:

```
<link title="myStyles" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Then use a function like this to check for the presence of a style within a particular styleseet:

```
function linkLoaded(linkTitle, checkStyle)
{
    for (var ix=0; ix<document.styleSheets.length; ix++) {
        try {
            if (document.styleSheets[ix].title == linkTitle) {
                var mySheet=document.styleSheets[ix];
                var myRules = mySheet.cssRules? mySheet.cssRules: mySheet.rules
                for (var jx=0; jx<myRules.length; jx++) {
                    var thisSelector = myRules[jx].selectorText.toLowerCase();
                    if (thisSelector.substring(0, checkStyle.length) == checkStyle) {
                        alert("Found style!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (err) {}    
    }

    alert("Not loaded!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes .cssRules and .rules will be null, so adding a if (css.rules) guard would be wise.