# coffee-script try and catch failing in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, coffeescript, try-catch

```
Radiant::loadCSS = (fn, scope) ->
  head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
  link = document.createElement("link")
  link.setAttribute "href", "/" + ri.context + "/css/" + @obj + ".css"
  link.setAttribute "rel", "stylesheet"
  link.setAttribute "type", "text/css"
  sheet = undefined
  cssRules = undefined
  if "sheet" of link
    sheet = "sheet"
    cssRules = "cssRules"
  else
    sheet = "styleSheet"
    cssRules = "rules"
  timeout_id = setInterval(->
    try
      if link[sheet] and link[sheet][cssRules].length
        clearInterval timeout_id
        clearTimeout timeout_id
        fn.call scope or window, true, link #LINE THAT ERRORS OUT!!!
    #finally
  , 10)
  timeout_id = setTimeout(->
    clearInterval timeout_id
    clearTimeout timeout_id
    head.removeChild link
    fn.call scope or window, false, link
  , 15000)
  head.appendChild link
  link
```

So above is my translation of a function ripped from here : [Dynamically loading css file using javascript with callback without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537622/dynamically-loading-css-file-using-javascript-with-callback-without-jquery)

When I had this in straight javascript it worked great, but the coffee version is giving me problems in ie8 `'fn' is null or not an object`

Here is the rendered javascript for that section:

```
timeout_id = setInterval(function() {
  try {
    if (link[sheet] && link[sheet][cssRules].length) {
      clearInterval(timeout_id);
      clearTimeout(timeout_id);
      return fn.call(scope || window, true, link); //ERROR LINE!!!
    }
  } catch (_error) {}
}, 10);
```

Anyway I am new to `try` and `catch` and just don't understand what is going wrong here. Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has less to do with try/catch and more to do with that for whatever reason, `fn` is not defined when the callback executes (as the error says).   Are you sure `fn` is passed into `loadCSS` in the cases where you get the error?

Comment: oh duh. I didn't pass in a callback function this time.