# How to make Bootstrap 3 responsive in IE8 (with dynamically loaded CSS)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't see a solution for the following problem: I have a page that dynamically loads it's CSS (e.g. Bootstrap 3 scripts). The solution to make it work is to [use respond.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5770956/454103), but this does this requires `respond.js` to be loaded **after** the CSS using media queries.

And when dynamically loading CSS, there [is no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537622/dynamically-loading-css-file-using-javascript-with-callback-without-jquery) to detect when the CSS file has been loaded (I also don't have jQuery).

What other approach should I try to add support for media queries in IE8 when no jQuery is available and when Bootstrap 3 is dynamically loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Recent i use javascript's onreadystatechange for defer loading of javascript, see http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-defer-loading/ and https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

I think you could use the same to solve your problem maybe:

```
function loadrespond(){
var respond_js = document.createElement("script");
respond_js.src = "assets/respond.js";
document.body.appendChild(respond_js);
}

var elementbootstrapcss = document.createElement("link");
elementbootstrapcss.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (this.readyState == 'complete') loadrespond();
}
elementbootstrapcss.onload = loadrespond;

elementbootstrapcss.href = 'assets/css/bootstrap.css';
elementbootstrapcss .rel = 'stylesheet';
elementbootstrapcss.type = 'text/css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(elementbootstrapcss);
```

CSS loading from: [CSS delivery optimization: How to defer css loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374843/css-delivery-optimization-how-to-defer-css-loading)