# Add classes to a Script line in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I hide a script line using CSS? for example if we added a class="slider" to the script line like below:

```
<script class="slider" type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slider.js"></script>
```

and then in css we did:

```
.slider {display: none}
```

The reason I want that is I want to enable the js when a specific style sheet is called

Comment: CSS is for **DISPLAY** control. A script tag is always hidden anyways. "hiding" it via CSS does NOT prevent the code from running. CSS can NOT be used to turn code on or off.

Comment: Why don't you select the stylesheet from within your script??

Comment: Thanks that answered my question. Any Idea tho how do I run a js when a specific style-sheet is being used?

Comment: @Severin How Do I Do That?

Comment: There is no "class" parameter for scripts. You cannot disable a script using CSS, you will have to use Javascript.

Comment: @APAD1: [Yes there is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html)

Comment: I don't see anywhere on that page that says "class" is an attribute for script, @Adrift.

Comment: Under **permissible attributes** it includes [Global Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html) which includes `class` - the same holds true for HTML 4.01

Comment: Permissible != functional

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this related question to find a way to include your CSS via JavaScript: [Dynamically loading css file using javascript with callback without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537622/dynamically-loading-css-file-using-javascript-with-callback-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

At least for the moment, assume you are only loading style sheets during document load.  Then, you can do the following:

```
function checkLoadedSheetsForHref(href) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; ++i) {
        if (document.styleSheets[i].href == href) {
        // or if you just want to check the filename, check if href contains it:
        // if (document.styleSheets[i].href.indexOf(href) != -1) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

document.onload = function() {
    if (checkLoadedSheetsForHref("assets/js/slider.js")) {
        // enable whatever js you want
    }
}
```

If you have something that dynamically loads style sheets, you could set timers to wait for the sheet to load, or add an `onload` to whatever is adding it, or just check the string you're loading.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so. Self explanatory:

```
var SliderVar = document.getElementById("slider");
if (SliderVar.style.display == "none") {
    var showScript = false;  
} else {
    var showScript = true;   
}
if(showScript) {
  var sc = document.createElement('script');
  sc.src = 'assets/js/slider.js';
  sc.type = 'text/javascript';
  if(typeof sc['async'] !== 'undefined') {
     sc.async = true;
  }  
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sc);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this to be honest, what does it do?

Comment: It sets a `var` named `showScript` with a default value of false. It is then set to `true` within the `if` statement if the condition is met. The condition being if the slider is set to display none then the script will not be included.