# How can I use Javascript event handlers in <link> having rel="author"

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onload, onerror

I want to use `onload()` or `onerror()` or any other Javascript event handler with:

```
<link rel="author" href="http://something.here" />
```

For example:

```
<link rel="author" href="http://something.here" onload="alert(1)" />
```

Is it possible? If yes then can anyone help me? I am trying to do this but its not working.

Comment: what is the behavior you expect?

Comment: But nothing will ever be loaded using `link rel="author"`...

Comment: then any other event handler @lonesomeday? I want to show up a pop up on any supported event @Sergio

Comment: Any event? like this?: `<div onmouseover="alert(1)" >Test</div>`, demo here http://jsfiddle.net/s7U3Z/

Comment: not with `<div>` but with `<link rel="author" />`....?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve in more general terms? Is the idea to call some JS code when the linked item finishes loading, or when it doesn't load because of an error, or...?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078584/link-element-onload

Comment: Yes @nnnnnn the idea is to call some JS code when the linked item finishes loading but the `rel` attribute should be `author`

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that I think as your real attribute. Your best bet is fetching something.here content. Or using PHP GET to send data to next page and use PHP if isset, you can not use event handlers from one page to other (maybe you could resort of using cookie or local storage on click but that is overkill of you ask me). When your new page loads its new show.

For example using ?get to send and fetch with JS:

```
<link rel="author" href="http://something.here?author=true" />
```

And when new page loads:

```
var loc= window.location.href;
  //get loacation

values=loc.split('?');
link=values[values.length-1];
//split it at ? and get : `author=true`


    if (value == "author=true") {
       // do something
    };
```

Or use PHP:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['author'])) {
// do somehing
} ?>
```