# CasperJS does not trigger properly on callback of dynamic script/link call

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have an issue with Casper JS and a sample html page.

The onLoad event on the external bootstrap call that i added dynamically is not triggered/handled on casper side. In my example, the screenshot will never be red but if i load the page from a browser then the page does look red.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = document.createElement("link");
    s.href = "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    s.rel = "stylesheet";
    s.type = "text/css";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the file called by casper:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('test.html', function() {
});

casper.wait(5000, function(){
    casper.capture("debug.png");
});

casper.run(function() {
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS (v1.9.7), the underlying headless browser of CasperJS, has the same features as Chrome 13 which, as it seems, does not support `onload` on `link` elements. If you need it, you might find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3078584/1816580) some workarounds.

Otherwise, the following code does what you want:

```
casper.start('test.html');

casper.waitForResource(/css/, function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
    this.capture("debug.png");
});
```

You can use `--enginge=slimerjs` with http://slimerjs.org/ to run the gecko engine from your installed firefox.

On an unrelated note. `link` elements are better suited in the `head` instead of `body`.