# How to run a function when CSS stylesheet finishes loading

Tags: javascript, css, image, onload, onload-event

How do I run a function when a stylesheet finishes loading?

Here is my code..

```
var d = document,
    css = d.head.appendChild(d.createElement('link'))

css.rel = 'stylesheet';
css.type = 'text/css';
css.href = "https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.10.0/css/tachyons.css"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MDN's [<link>: The External Resource Link element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events),

> You can determine when a style sheet has been loaded by watching for a `load` event to fire on it; similarly, you can detect if an error has occurred while processing a style sheet by watching for an `error` event:
>
> ```
> <script>
> var myStylesheet = document.querySelector('#my-stylesheet');
>
> myStylesheet.onload = function() {
>   // Do something interesting; the sheet has been loaded
> }
>
> myStylesheet.onerror = function() {
>   console.log("An error occurred loading the stylesheet!");
> }
> </script>
>
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css" id="my-stylesheet">
> ```
>
> <sub>Note: The `load` event fires once the stylesheet and all of its imported content has been loaded and parsed, and immediately before the styles start being applied to the content.</sub>

Comment: The link does not show onload or load in the Browser compatibility so it may not support old browsers. Neither caniuse.com give result. Found a duplicat with same problem that onload does not work on script elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078584/link-element-onload

Comment: I accept your answer. See my answer how to extend your code to be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho But if your answer is better, by all means feel free to accept that one. It's about the content of the answers, not the authors.

Comment: Yes, we contribute all together for the content of Q&A.

Comment: My answer was based on code I now removed to archives. It becomes forgotten knowledge. I think even "industrial quality production code" can rely on `.onload` nowadays. Look: http://kangax.github.io/jstests/script-element-onload-attribute-support

Comment: But uh - now I see the support table was to <script> and not <link>. It works back to 2011 with <link> and IE10 came 2012 that is my reference to be backwards compatible with my code. ES5 was already out. So no worry - this is still a safe solution even for CSS.

Answer (score -1):

This is a cross-browser solution optimized for modern browsers accepting [CSS onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events). It works back to 2011 when only Opera and Internet Explorer supported the onload event and onreadystatechange respectively on css. See link below.

```
var d = document,
    css = d.head.appendChild(d.createElement('link')),
    src = "https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.10.0/css/tachyons.css"

css.rel = 'stylesheet';
css.type = 'text/css';
css.href = src
```

Add this after the loader

```
if (typeof css.onload != 'undefined') css.onload = myFun;
else {
    var img = d.createElement("img");
    img.onerror = function() {
      myFun();
      d.body.removeChild(img);
    }
    d.body.appendChild(img);
    img.src = src;
}

function myFun() {
    /* ..... CONTINUE CODE HERE ..... */
}
```

The answer is based on [this link](https://www.viget.com/articles/js-201-run-a-function-when-a-stylesheet-finishes-loading/) that say:

> What happens behind the scenes is that the browser tries to load the
>   CSS in the **img** element and, because a stylesheet is not a type of
>   image, the **img** element throws the **onerror** event and executes our
>   function. Thankfully, browsers load the entire CSS file before
>   determining its not an image and firing the **onerror** event.